# Subqueries in MSSQL producing NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to determine my store only accounts revenue from the database, to do this I need to look through all account numbers with revenue against a 'store' description who do NOT appear in a list of accounts with an 'online' description which I have tried todo in the subquery below. The query runs however it just returns NULL values in my store_only_revenue column. Any guidance on what to do from here would be appreciated. Am I approaching the problem in a good way? Or is there a better solution:

```
 SELECT 
    town,
    financial_pd as month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Descr] = 'online' THEN Net_Revenue ELSE 0 END) as online_revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Descr] = 'store' THEN Net_Revenue ELSE 0 END) as store_revenue,

    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Descr] = 'online' THEN Account_Number ELSE NULL END) as online_accounts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Descr] = 'store' THEN Account_Number ELSE NULL END) as store_accounts,


    (SELECT 
    SUM(Net_Revenue)

      FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]

      WHERE 

      Descr = 'store'
      AND Account_Number

      NOT IN(
      SELECT DISTINCT Account_Number
      FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
      WHERE 
      Descr = 'online')

      ) as store_only_revenue

     FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] as orders


     WHERE 

      Group_name = 'T' 
      AND NOT 
      Type_name_1 = 'Electronic' 
      AND 
      Account_type <> 1                 
      AND
      Total_Value > 0
      AND
      (Insert_Date BETWEEN '2016-05-30' AND '2016-07-03'
      OR
      Insert_Date BETWEEN '2015-05-25' AND '2015-06-28')
      OR
      (Insert_Date BETWEEN '2016-05-30' AND '2016-07-03'
      AND
      Insert_Date BETWEEN '2015-05-25' AND '2015-06-28')


      GROUP BY 
      town,
      financial_pd as period
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression is suspect:

```
Account_Number NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t.Account_Number
                       FROM [mydb].[dbo].mytable t
                       WHERE t.Descr = 'online'
                      )
```

Assuming that the syntax problems are typos (missing table name, `desc` is a reserved word), then this will never return true if even one `Account_Number` is `NULL`.  One way to fix this is:

```
Account_Number NOT IN (SELECT t.Account_Number
                       FROM [mydb].[dbo].mytable t
                       WHERE t.Desc = 'online' AND t.Account_Number IS NOT NULL
                      )
```

I would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
not exists (select 1
            from [mydb].[dbo].??? x
            where x.Desc = 'online' AND ??.Account_Number = x.Account_Number
           )
```

You need to use proper table aliases for this to work.  Either of these solutions may fix your problem.

Comment: Using the first solution is generates values for each row. However, the result is the same aggregate SUM for each town? Is this because I have not specified the town within the sub query? As I understand I cannot return more than 1 column within a sub query. (I have also fixed some of the typos within the original code - apologies for this).

Comment: @AEJBUG . . . Hmmm, try it with fully qualified column names (using table aliases), and see if that works.

Comment: I have tried adding in the aliases as suggested above, but I still get the same figure in all of my rows for the store_only_revenue column.